Molecular quantum dynamics: wavepacket oscillating more than I would expect
I am venturing into the exciting world of molecular quantum dynamics. MCTDH is my tool for the task. I've done some of the tutorials in the manual and, with the knowledge I have acquired, have begun to carry out test cases for the system I am interested on. Specifically, I carried out 2D ab-initio calculations for a linear (A-X-A) triatomic, scanning along the asymmetric stretch and bend modes. using the potfit and chnpot functionality of MCTDH, I have generated appropriate potentials for the use in the dynamics. Now, to the observation that is puzzling me. Below you'll find a cut along the asymmetric stretch mode:

I prepare the initial wave packet centered at equilibrium

and within a femtosecond it has already begun to r = +- 0.4 a.u., which corresponds to about 2.0 ev of energy!!

This is... not what I would expect. I would expect it to remain localized near the bottom of the well. Am I misunderstanding quantum dynamics? If I am not, what could be causing the wave packet to begin slushing around violently if it has been prepared at equilibrium? (Or, I believe I have at least. Below you'll find the INIT_WF-SECTION from my MCTDH input file.)
INIT_WF-SECTION
 BUILD
 # Mode  type    x_0     p_o   frequency (eV)  reduced mass (amu)
   r      HO     0.00   0.00    0.1457718,ev   15.99491463,amu
   t      HO     0.00   0.00    0.0248465,ev   17.98200000,amu
 END-BUILD
end-init_wf-section

Edit for additional discovery
See the answer...

+1 but upon a very quick glance, this result doesn't surprise me. The wavefunction will change drastically, very quickly, because of the function exp(-iHt).

But it shouldnt if it's very close to the ground state, right? I think at this point I am puzzled as to why my initial wave function is, indeed so far away from the ground state.

In your edit of the question, about 1 hour before your comment here, you pointed out that with an initial state that is closer to the ground state, you didn't get as much of a change in the wavefunction. Therefore it seems that your initial question has been answered, and I suggest that you write a self-answer saying that changing your initial wavefunction solved your problem. Your next question is about how your initial guess could be so far away from the ground state, and that needs to be asked in a separate post in order to comply with the "1 question per post" policy.

Agreed. Will write a self-answer.

Upon using the relaxation (imaginary time propagation) functionality of MCTDH from the initial wave function presented above, the wave function quickly converges to its ground state.

As you can appreciate, it is a much broader Gaussian. If I use this a starting function for a real time propagation, naturally and as one would expect for the ground state, it doesnt move at all. So it just turns out that my initial wave function was not exactly the ground state and that is why it was oscillating. As to how to properly-prepare close-to-ground state wave functions from the INIT-WF_SECTION, I'll post that as a separate question.
